# Android gradient emboss effect

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve from code the following: (can't post images unfortunatelly)

A rectangle with rounded corners, with an emboss effect (the light comes from top left corner).
In the middle there is a circle engraved in the rectangle. Imagine a water surface, and a drop of water hits the surface. It creates a dent in the surface. That circle is also painted with some linear gradient.

The problem is I could only use the EmbossMaskFilter from Android to raise the surface, to make it closer to the user eye, but I don't know how to implement the opposite.
Anyone can help me with that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a composite drawable, or drawables in layers.

To create a drawable with rounded corners and a gradient within, use something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/gradientstart" android:endColor="@color/gradientend" android:angle="315"/>
</shape>
```

Create two such drawables and put them on top of each other to create the required effect.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it doesn't help me to obtain the pillow emboss (engrave) effect for the inner circle that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a pretty good number of layer-list items as a drawable you probably won't get the effect you are looking for easily with XML drawables. A better solution would be to create a 9-patch image. See how it works at [draw9patch.com](http://draw9patch.com/), which is a tool to create 9 patch images from a standard images.

NinePatch documentation: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

In case, you still really want to use xml drawables you can still achieve the effect (although performance *might* take a hit) using a [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with multiple gradients stacked ontop of each other.